# Matlab: how to sort data descent excluding NaN

Tags: matlab, sorting, nan

Say I have a row:

**NaN** 29.99 30.00 **NaN** 24.32 **NaN** ...............

How can I sort the data in descending order and select the top 10% largest number?

The 'sort' function will put NaN as the "largest"~~~ how can I exclude it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first sort the row, and then exclude the NaN's

```
sorted_row = sorted_row( ~isnan(sorted_row) );
```

This will remove all NaNs from the sorted row.

Better Yet, to save computations , you should exclude NaNs before you sort.

```
sorted_row = sort( row(~isnan(row)) );
```

Comment: I don't believe that `row ~= NaN` works as expected.  For example `x = [1 2 NaN];  x(x~=NaN)` will return `x = 1 2 NaN`.  You have to use `x(~isnan(x))`

Answer (score 1):

Try using after sort:
`sorted_row(~isnan(sorted_row))`

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to select the top 10% largest numbers you can use [QUANTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/quantile.html) or [PRCTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/prctile.html) functions from Statistical Toolbox (no sort needed):

```
x_largest = x(x >= quantile(x, 0.9));
```

or

```
x_largest = x(x >= prctile(x, 90));
```

Those functions don't take NaNs into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
[~, iSort] = sort(x, 'descend'); % Sort x including NaNs
iSort(isnan(x(iSort))) = []; % Now remove indices to sorted x which are NaNs
```